# Is (research on) taxonomies/folksonomies/hierarchies of meaning on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Taxonomies/folksonomies/hierarchies of meaning/semantic hierarchies is part of library science and computational linguistics (machine translation, nlp) among no doubt many others. An important semantic hierarchy *used* in linguistics are the various wordnets, starting with the original for English from Princeton. So *use* of taxonomies should be on-topic.

But: would the more theoretical sides to taxonomies, like how to make them, judge them for suitability and quality etc. be on-topic here?<sub>If you do go down that particular rabbit-hole you might never come back up :)</sub>

Comment: These are called "ontologies" as Mitch also states in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, use and development of particular ontologies -or- study of them in general would be totally on-topic here. Of course, the question may get better vocabulary answers (for particular ontologies) from a language specific site like EL&U.